# How to iterate over a nested TreeMap without creating temporary Objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, treemap, temporary-objects

I'm working on a nGrams, and I'm using a nested TreeMap kind of datastructure to store the ngrams. The template for Quadgrams looks like this.

```
public TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>>>> ngramWordCounter;
```

The problem is arising when i'm trying to dump it to a file, basically i'm iterating over keySet of first map, and then into the keymap of the second and so on and so forth. As a result a lot of temporary objects are created and i'm getting GCOverlimitExceeded Error. The code snippet for iterating is as follows,

```
for(String key: ((Quadgram)quadgram).ngramWordCounter.keySet())
{
  for(String key1: ((Quadgram)quadgram).ngramWordCounter.get(key).keySet())
  {
    for(String key2: ((Quadgram)quadgram).ngramWordCounter.get(key).get(key1).keySet())
    {
        for(String key3:((Quadgram)quadgram).ngramWordCounter.get(key).get(key1).get(key2).keySet())
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a better way to iterate over this list without creating temporary objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New objects won't be created. new references will be created.

Map returns reference to key in keyset.  Use [this reference](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html) to explore this concept or you can read java tutorials about this concept.

I prefer following way to iterate map is

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            // process key and value
}
```

Comment: What happens to the references `String key` and `String value` after the loop terminates? These variables needs to be sweeped by GarbageCollector as Strings are indeed objects. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406703/when-will-a-string-be-garbage-collected-in-java]

Comment: yeah references will be removed not actual objects. If you check implementation, internally TreeMap stores Entry object itself. But all processing is inside the loop (guessing from given sample code)