# Java: does pool of strings saves string literals that

Tags: java, jvm

Please look at the following Java code:

```
String greeting = "Hello" + "World";
```

It's clear that both string literals "Hello" and "World" are created in pools of strings. Still, after this line executes, do they stay them for the entire lifetime of the application even though there is no reference pointing them?

Comment: Who said they go into the thread pool? And if they do, why would they be removed?

Comment: An object is supposed to be removed if there is no reference pointing to it.

Comment: The string pool isn't garbage collected.

Comment: @shmosel *String pool isn't garbage collected* - are you sure about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407081/303810

Comment: I guess they can be, technically. But you're not unloading classes, are you?

Comment: @shmosel *Who said they go into the string pool?* - the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

Comment: @lexicore [I think you're mistaken.](https://ideone.com/lSBEua)

Comment: 'It's clear that both string literals "Hello" and "World" are created in pools of strings': no it isn't. This is a compile-time expression. The single literal `"HelloWorld"` is pooled, for as long as the class remains loaded. @lexicore

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406703/when-will-a-string-be-garbage-collected-in-java says that every string literal is pooled. "Hello" and "World" are string literals.

Comment: @CrazySyntax But they aren't pooled. The total expression is pooled. See the [JLS link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) provided by lexicore, the part where it refers to #15.28. A StackOverflow answer isn't a normative reference.

Comment: @schmosel You're both mistaken in detail. The fundamental premiss of the question is incorrect.

Comment: @EJP What am I mistaken about?

Comment: @CrazySynthax - I have (ermm) clarified the part of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406703/when-will-a-string-be-garbage-collected-in-java that some people have (ermm) misinterpreted.  But ... please ... you should NOT be relying on StackOverflow Q&A's as your definitive source of information.  If you want to debate what the Java language spec says, **read** the JLS.  Don't be lazy and just rely on someone else's summary.

Comment: (And in case someone wants to say that the JLS is too hard to understand, I would respond 1) No it isn't ... in this area.  2) No it isn't in general ... if you put in the time. 3) If you don't have the time, you would be wise to stay out if this kind of "language lawyer" debate.  Leave it to the people who do have the time / interest / patience to read and understand the JLS.)