# Spring Security uses java.lang.String to transfer user passwords. Isn't this a security flaw?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, passwords

We all have been told to always use `char[]` instead of `java.lang.String` to handle plain text passwords in Java applications. Due to the immutable nature of `java.lang.String` that allows attackers to take a heap snapshot (before GC kicked in) and read the passwords from that snapshot.

Now I'm surprised to see spring-security using `String` to transfer passwords. E.g. in [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html).

Is this a security issue? And if no, why not? If yes, how can I safely use spring-security without revealing passwords in the Java heap or at least minimizing the risk of revealing them?

See [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Comment: If I take a heap snapshot and you have passwords stored in a `char[]` I can grab them too. Using `char[]` is what we call "security through obscurity". It's "security theater". Look! We care about security. They don't! But if I have control of the machine, I can read anything in your user level application at any time (without you, as a user, knowing).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, sure I can read `char[]` contents from a heap dump as well. To my understanding the best practice should be to clear the `char[]` after you're finished with handling the password. To minimize the possibilities of such attacks. But with `String` you can't clear anything and have to wait for the GC to free the memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407081/2970947 Meh. If you want to go back to explicit memory management, use C or C++.