# RAM does not clear even after calling System.gc()

Tags: java, heap-memory

This is a sample code of my main application problem. When I generate the data it continues to take the RAM (by the way its OK). But when I stop the process it still remain in the RAM (I can see it in the Task Manager). I tried to use the `System.gc()` but it also didn't work. At some point the program got stuck, because of it taking up more memory. Hope somebody can help me.

```
public static ArrayList<String> my = new ArrayList<>();
public static int val = 0;
```

```
// Code for Start Button 
try {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String ss = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                ss += "ABC";
            }
            while (true) {
                if (val == 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        my.add(ss + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                } else {
                    Thread.yield();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
// Code for Stop Button
val = 1;
my.clear();
my = null;
System.gc();
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573/10303335) asnwer. Seems to me that it covers your question mostly.

Comment: There is no Swing mentioned anywhere in the uncompilable code snippet. Why is that tag added? Try and reproduce it without any Swing classes. If it depends on the Swing API, post a [mre] of that. BTW - The JVM will do garbage collection when it feels it is necessary. Unless the code is throwing `OutOfMemoryError` I doubt it is necessary.

Comment: *"when I stop the process"* How can you run `gc()` if you've stopped the Java process? How can you see it in the Task Manager if you've stopped the Java process?

Comment: @Andreas: I don't think OP really means the process, I think they mean their 'Stop Button' which sets a shared field which _should_ cause the `while` loop in the `run` method to `break` -- although since it isn't `volatile` or used in `synchronized` the Java memory model doesn't promise this will work. OP: garbage collection doesn't normally return memory to the OS, only makes it available for use by new allocations within the same JVM process.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't think so either, but that is what OP said, so if OP meant something else, then OP needs to edit the question and clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection depends on the various factor like which collector you're using, machine's physical memory as well as the JVM version you are using. Since you're not mentioned so much here about them, bit hard to predict which could be the cause for this. I assume you're using Java 8 since that's the more popular version nowadays.

Since Java 8, There's a change in JVM memory model. Which is, now there is no `Permanent Generation` space. This's the space where `String Pool` located (I'm going with `String` hence you're using a `String` concatenation in loops). Refer this [Java (JVM) Memory Model – Memory Management in Java](https://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-memory-management-in-java) document. `Permanent Generation` is where the class/static references live since you declare them as well.

Instead of `Permanent Generation`, Since Java 8, there's a new memory location called `Metaspace` which lives in the Main memory outside of JVM.

Also, when you concatenate `String` objects like this, it won't modify the existing object as `String` is immutable type. Instead, it creates new `String` objects with the new value and put them into the `Metaspace`. This might be the reason you're seeing a memory usage increment.

Even though `Metaspace` is located inside the main memory/physical memory and it can dynamically expand, still has the physical memory limitation. That's why I told earlier machine's physical memory as a dependency factor.

When we come to garbage collection, you haven't mention any GC config. So I assume you are using **Parallel GC** which is the default collector of Java 8 (You can find more about the GCs from same link provided above). I guess the `Parallel GC`'s performance is adequate for this task. Therefore invoking `System.gc()` whould be enough without any JVM flag.

But, as you mentioned that `System.gc()` doesn't clean up the memory could occurs hence you're using a separate thread to concatenate these Strings.

Usually, Strings that created using String literal (`String s = "abc"`) would not become garbage eligible. This because there is a **implicit** reference to the `String` object in the code of every method that uses the literal (Check this answer [When will a string be garbage collected in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406703/when-will-a-string-be-garbage-collected-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top)). Thus, you have to loose those implicit references by ending the execution of the function.

Since you're using a new `Thread` to do this concatenation and I can't find any place where you interrupt the thread and you're invoking the `Thread.yield()`([Thread.yield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield())) to inform the thread scheduler to seize the usage of the CPU for this particular thread and mark the thread is willing to be scheduled as soon as possible again, make pretty much clear this `Thread` object still lives and refers those String objects not making them garbage eligible. This maybe the reason `System.gc()` invocation is not working.

As a solution, try to `interrupt` the thread instead of `yield`.

**Update 1:**

Before Java 7, `String Pool` was located in `PermGen`, which is not eligible for garbage collection. `PermGen` has a fixed size and not capable to expand at runtime. If `PermGen` has not enough space, it gives `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` error. As a temporary remediation we can increase the `PermGen` size using `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` flag.

But remember this is only works on JVMs before Java 8 and in Java 7, this doesn't make any different in the sense of increasing `String Pool` size availability hence Java 7 onwards, `String Pool` has moved to `Heap` space.

Comment: `String`s weren't in PermGen before and aren't in Metaspace now. Note the `Thread.yield()` is followed by `break` which causes the Thread function to return and therefore the Thread exits -- if the `val=1` gets seen at all by this Thread.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I guess, `String Pool` was in `PermGen` (Before Java 7)  and after moved to `Heap` space. So, afterwards it should be in `Heap` space, Not in `Meatspace`. My bad.

Comment: @SachithDickwella Thank you very much for your explained answer. As Im new to java it really helped me a lot to understand my error