# Is the Class object A created when the JVM loads class A, or when I call A.class?

Tags: java, class, jvm, synchronize

As I know, every class has a `Class` object. There is one case when I use synchronize, for example:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String... args){
        synchronize(A.class){
            //do something...
        }
    }
}
```

This will lock `A`'s `Class` object, right? When is this `Class` object created? Is it created when the JVM loads the `A` class or when I call `A.class`? I can't find detail in JLS, could someone please provide the link about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this will lock A's Class object, right?

yes.

> my question is when this Class object is created? is it created at JVM load A class or when i call A.class?

When the ClassLoader loads it, it returns a `Class` object.

> i can't find detail in JLS, could someone please provide the link about it, thanks.

I suggest reading the javadoc for the [ClassLoader.loadClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-boolean-)

Comment: hi, Peter, also the same question, can it gc?

Comment: @Tony a class can be GCed only if it's class loader is GC'ed. This means all instances of all classes for the classloader are no longer strongly referenced.  The main/default ClassLoader is never GC'ed.

Comment: thanks, A a = new A(), i can say a is an instance of A class, but A's Class object is who's instance, if it is belong to A, i don't think a = Class object

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is only in theory. In practice classloaders are never garbage collected

Comment: @Gaskoin i don't think so, in order to your words, class is never GC'ed, right? we can have custom classloader.

Comment: @Gaskoin in an Application servers such as OSGi server, class loaders are unloaded regulary.  In plain Java programs you need to load an additional ClassLoader if you want to be able to unload that code later. It doesn't have to be a custom one.

Comment: But OSGi servers have custom ClassLoaders:D In specific cases they have 1 classloader per jar file thus when classes from jar are not used anymore the classloader is unloaded. This is very specific case -> that is the reason that I wrote that in practice ClassLoaders are never garbage collected during your application runtime. They can be in OSGi during deployment, but it is very rare case during application runtime.

Comment: hi, could someone can answer my earlier sub question, whose instance is Class object(A) is?

Comment: @Tony A.class is an instance of Class. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @PeterLawrey okay, is this Class object GC before or after class A GC'ed

Comment: @Tony There is only one object to represent the class.

Answer (score 2):

It is created when the class is loaded by the JVM as the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) states:

> `Class` has no public constructor. Instead `Class` objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the `defineClass` method in the class loader.

Comment: every class just have one instance of Class object, right? can it  gc?

Comment: Yes one instance only. [It can be GC'd in extreme cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433261/when-and-how-are-classes-garbage-collected-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

A class is initialized by a [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) when the class is first used, [JLS 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> [5.3. Creation and Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3)
>
> Creation of a class or interface C denoted by the name N consists of
>   the construction in the method area of the Java Virtual Machine
>   (§2.5.4) of an implementation-specific internal representation of C.
>   **Class or interface creation is triggered by another class or interface D, which references C** through its run-time constant pool.
>   **Class or interface creation may also be triggered by D invoking
>   methods in certain Java SE platform class libraries (§2.12) such as
>   reflection**.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it created when the JVM loads the A class

Yes.

> or when I call A.class?

No. The JVM loads A when a class that uses it is loaded, apart from the special case of reflection, which doesn't apply here.